# How to copy files from file server to windows node with ansible?

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, robocopy

I am trying to copy files from a windows file server to one of the windows node with `robocopy` module.  Find below files I am trying with.

```
[ipa@ansible VDITesting]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.5
  config file = /home/ipa/VDITesting/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ipa/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]

[ipa@ansible VDITesting]$ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
inventory=./hosts

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=runas
become_user=administrator
become_ask_pass=False

[ipa@ansible VDITesting]$ cat hosts 
[windows]
node1.MYDOMAIN.NET

[windows:vars]
ansible_user=appuser
ansible_password=My_p@ss
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=kerberos
ansible_python_interpreter=C:\Python36\python.exe
[ipa@ansible VDITesting]$ cat playbook-test.yaml 
---
- name: Windows 
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
   - name: Copy app scripts
     win_robocopy:
       src: \\file_server\pub\Win10Setup\
       dest: C:\opt\test\apps
```

Getting bellow error.

```
TASK [Copy app scripts] **************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node1.MYDOMAIN.NET]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\opt\\test\\apps", "msg": "\\\\file_server\\pub\\Win10Setup\\ does not exist!", "purge": false, "recurse": false, "src": "\\\\file_server\\pub\\Win10Setup\\"}
```

I manually checked the path exist. Working on it for couple of days but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I found out we need to create credential for the file server before using robocopy module. It resolved the issue. Find here how to create credentials https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_credential_module.html.